# Assigning Object ID of Managed Identity in key_vault_access_policy

Tags: azure-managed-identity

I'm trying to assign the Object ID of my User_Managed_Identity to the KeyVault_Access_Policy

The Managed_Identity will need to Get & List the Certificates from my KeyVault. I've been following Terraform Documentation.

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/role_assignment

```
# User Assigned Identity
resource "azurerm_user_assigned_identity" "user_assigned_identity" {
  location            = "west europe"
  name                = "Identity_Name"
  resource_group_name = "Resource_Group_Name"
}

# Access Policy
data "azurerm_client_config" "example" {
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "access_policy" {
  key_vault_id = "000000-000000-000000-000000"
  tenant_id    = data.azurerm_client_config.example.tenant_id
  object_id    = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.user_assigned_identity.id

  certificate_permissions = [
    "Get","List",
  ]
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: expected "object_id" to be a valid UUID, got /subscriptions/0000000-0000-0000-0000-0000000000/resourceGroups/Resource_Group_Name/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/Identity_Name
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd think it should be:

```
azurerm_user_assigned_identity.user_assigned_identity.principal_id
```

what you are doing right now - is using resource id, not object id